# How do I add clearInterval to my JS timer?

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I've made a timer in JavaScript, but when the start button is repeatedly clicked it keeps getting faster. I know clearInterval is used to stop this, but depending on where I put it in the code it either stops the timer from working completely or makes no difference. This is the code, I put it on the fourth line but it's not doing anything:

```
var minutes;
var seconds;
function PomodoroBreak(x){
    clearInterval(interval)
    minutes = x;
    seconds = 0;
    

    var interval = setInterval(
        function(){
            var el = document.getElementById("timer")
            if(seconds ==0 && minutes==0){
                clearInterval(interval)
                el.innerHTML = "00:00"
                
            }
            else if(seconds == 0){
                minutes = minutes -1;
                seconds = 59
                el.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds
            }else if(seconds > 0){
                seconds = seconds -1;
                el.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds
                document.title = minutes + ":" + seconds
            }
           
           
        
        },
    
        1000
    )
  

}
```

Where am I supposed to put it instead, or have I done something else wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Try declaring `interval` outside the function, just as you've done with `minutes` and `seconds`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing some adjustments to be done here. I believe returning clearInterval with the startTimer declared above should do the work.
Hope this helps.

```
function PomodoroBreak(x){
    var minutes = x;
    var seconds = 0;

    let startTimer = setInterval(...,1000)
    return clearInterval(startTimer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare the variable “interval“ outside the function. And remove the var in the function.

```
var minutes;
var seconds;
var interval;

function PomodoroBreak(x){
clearInterval(interval)
minutes = x;
seconds = 0;


interval = setInterval(
    function(){
        var el = document.getElementById("timer")
        if(seconds ==0 && minutes==0){
            clearInterval(interval)
            el.innerHTML = "00:00"
            
        }
        else if(seconds == 0){
            minutes = minutes -1;
            seconds = 59
            el.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds
        }else if(seconds > 0){
            seconds = seconds -1;
            el.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds
            document.title = minutes + ":" + seconds
        }
       
       
    
    },

    1000
)


}
```